# TFS online get last checkin code to my solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

I have connected to Visual Studio Online from my desktop Visual studio. I am doing a checkin and commenting it. ("Person class added.") After I did some changes on project, I want to return a checkin that I want. Can I get the last changes to my visual studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In source control explorer in VS, right click the directory or file you want to get the specific version on. Navigate to Advanced -> Get Specific version.  that will open a dialog box with the options to select the changeset or date to get.

Also see:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181413(v=vs.110).aspx